# Cypher query returning null values even when the pattern is available in database

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

Is something wrong with this cypher query

```
MATCH (owner:SidNode)<-[:OWNED_BY]-(acl:AclNode)-[:SECURES]->(class:ClassNode) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (acl)<-[:COMPOSES]-(ace:AceNode)-[:AUTHORIZES]->(sid:SidNode) 
WITH acl, ace, owner, sid, class 
    WHERE  (acl.objectIdIdentity = {objectIdIdentity1} AND class.className = {className1})   
RETURN 
owner.principal AS aclPrincipal, 
owner.sid AS aclSid, 
acl.objectIdIdentity AS objectIdIdentity, 
ace.aceOrder AS aceOrder, 
ID(acl) AS aclId, 
acl.parentObject AS parentObject, 
acl.entriesInheriting AS entriesInheriting, 
ID(ace) AS aceId, ace.mask AS mask, 
ace.granting AS granting, 
ace.auditSuccess AS auditSuccess, 
ace.auditFailure AS auditFailure, 
sid.principal AS acePrincipal, 
sid.sid AS aceSid, 
class.className AS className  
ORDER BY acl.objectIdIdentity ASC, ace.aceOrder ASC
```

It is returning null values for ace nodes even though there are multiple nodes available in graph db.
But some times it is returning proper values like 4 rows if there are 4 ace nodes in db.
code i am writing is about spring security acl 
reference link:
https://github.com/shazin/spring-security-acl-neo4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/acls/neo4j/Neo4jLookupStrategy.java

Please suggest modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from `OPTIONAL MATCH`, according to [Neo4j's documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-optional-match.html), `OPTIONAL MATCH` returns `NULL`if the property or the element is not found.

You are getting `NULL` values because of this. If your acl node doesn't have any ace node related to him, the node will be replaced with `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

You bind the ace nodes in an optional match. When that optional match fails to match something, `ace` will be null.

If you think the optional match ought to be successful in cases when it is not, maybe you could provide an example. A good way to do so is to create a small sample graph at http://console.neo4j.org

The conditions in your `WHERE` clause look like they belong with your `MATCH` clause. You might want to move the `WHERE` clause up and you can then remove the `WITH` altogether. It won't affect nulls, but it will make your query more efficient and more readable. (Also, you don't need parentheses in your `WHERE` clause.)

```
MATCH (owner:SidNode)<-[:OWNED_BY]-(acl:AclNode)-[:SECURES]->(class:ClassNode)
WHERE acl.objectIdIdentity = {objectIdIdentity1} AND class.className = {className1}
OPTIONAL MATCH (acl)<-[:COMPOSES]-(ace:AceNode)-[:AUTHORIZES]->(sid:SidNode)
RETURN ...
```